# Drupal 7 js popup

Tags: 7, javascript

Trying to put a popup window on my drupal 7 site that hides/shows on click.

Here's the popup.js file:

```
Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
attach: function(context, settings) {

function donpopup(cat) {
  $('div.popup-dialog').hide();
  $('div#popup-dialog-' + cat).show();
  return false;
}

function closepop() {
 $('div.popup-dialog').hide();
}

}
};


})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

Here's the css:

```
 div.popup-dialog {
 display:none;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #AAAAAA;
 left: 25px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
 width: 300px;
 z-index: 100;
 }

 div.popcls{
 float:right;
 display:block;
 overflow:hidden;
 }
```

And here's the html

```
 <div style="position: relative;">
  <div id="don-cat-ST" class="don-catpop">
    <div class="popcls"><a onclick="closepop();return false;" href="#">x</a></div>
      <!-- Place the content here. -->
  <div>
</div>
```

I made sure that I added my js file in the theme .info..

But it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anywhere that donpopup(cat) is called. there's an onclick to close it, but I don't see one to open it.

Comment: Oh duh.. you're right. I'm a js newb, I snagged this from an online tutorial and then spent an hour figuring out how to get js files to load in drupal. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: actually.. i don't think this does what I want it to at all. If I understand this right, this starts with the window already popped up. And I need to show/hide on a click. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: In short, a function that is locale to `Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior.attach()` is not global; therefore, it is not visible outside `Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior.attach()`. This is a plain JavaScript question, not a Drupal question.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this for a small website and I used some drupal modules, rather than trying to hardcode stuff like this.

I used [ctools_automodal](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal). You supply a `hook_menu` function with a special key `modal => TRUE`. You then supply a page callback that uses `drupal_get_form` to show your modal content. The content need not be a full on form persay, you can use `$form['#markup']` to show non form stuff like paragraphs and images. From the project page it looks like this:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['mymodule/form'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer mymodule'),
    'modal' => TRUE, // This line is where the magic happens.
  );
}

// your custom form content could look like this:
function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['info'] = array(
  '#markup' => "<p>Some Info here ...</p>",
  );
}
```

Then the last part you need to do is put a link to this custom modal window using the [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/) or the [url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/) function, or like [views_linkarea](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_linkarea). The link must be generated by Drupal and not plain old HTML as you've done.

By using the modules above and the drupal API your popup window is more incorporated into Drupal, and if you want to add Panels or alter forms to include this popup link it's very easy. Also, note you haven't written an Javascript -- the ctools_automodal module is *hiding* all the complexity from you :).

Simply add CSS rules that target this modal form to style it as you need.

Comment: this would work, but i'm curious what the hardcoded version would look like.

i'm digging into changing css onclick to hide/show now

Comment: hmm, then i recommend debugging your webpage using Firebug what pieces of the code is broken. It's simply an academic task to find the errors. 1 benefit of drupal is to "stand on the shoulders of others" and not need to debug boilerplate hand-written code such as your example.